# Show row index and reset sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I am a WPF-noob and have two DataGrid problems:

***Problem 1:***

**What I got:**
A DataGird that gets its data from a array:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dgMain" ItemsSource="{Binding TestArray}" Margin="0,20,0,0" LoadingRow="dgMain_LoadingRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

I am using the "LoadingRow" event to update the row header:

```
private void dgMain_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
    }
```

**What I want:** 
It should show the index of the line in the row header.

**Whats the problem?:** If I add items or load items it works great, but if I sort the DataGird the index of the lines don't change.

[image: unsorted]
[image: sorted]

The left one is unsorted and the right one is sorted (by Name). In this example the index of line "F" should be 6 instead of 1 (right image).

(Not related to the problem: Why are all RowHeaders selected?)

***Problem 2:***

**What I got:** *see Problem 1*

**What I want:** After I added a row it should jump to the next empty row.

**Whats the problem?:** If I sort the datagrid it jumps to the next line, even if it is not empty.

[image: monkey]

First I sorted the list by name and then I added "A: First", "B: Second", "C: Third" and then "A: Fourth" and because of the sorting "A: Fourth" automatically gets the second line and then it jumps to the third line instead to the last, empty line.

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to say: It should 1. reset the sorting and 2. jump to the last, empty line. The order should be "A: First", "B: S", "C: T" and "A: Fourth".

I really hope there are easy solutions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first problem you must create your own row header style (you will probably need to change style to fit your design). Data grid should look something like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMain" ItemsSource="{Binding TestArray}" Margin="0,20,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3" BorderBrush="Black" Width="40">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Padding="2,1,1,1"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For`{Binding Index}` part you must extend your model with Id property which will hold index of every item. You should populate that index (int) when you are creating item model. In my test example I have used static variable like in example bellow:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    private static int counter = 0;
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime Age { get; set; }

    public ItemModel(string name, string address, DateTime? age = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
        Age = age ?? DateTime.Now;
        Index = ++counter;
    }
}
```

For your second problem: I think you can not return in easy way to original sorting. However, you can do something like:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // clear sorting!
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in this.dgMain.Columns)
    {
        column.SortDirection = null;
    }

    testArray.Add(new ItemModel("A:fourth", "ee"));
}
```

Before you add new value to your observable collection (I hope you are using observable collection, even you wrote"A DataGird that gets its data from a array:") you must cleared for every datagrid column its sorting. Doing that, you will always add newly created item on the last position of datagrid. However, as I already said, order of previous rows will stay untouched. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks ^^ And yes, I use a observable collection :)

Comment: Found a solution to reset the sorting:

var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgMain.ItemsSource);
            view.SortDescriptions.Clear();